# Eclipse SWT Hello world tutorial: Display cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, swt, eclipse-luna

I just installed Eclipse Luna v 4.4.2. I was running through the tutorials after installing the Java Developer Tools and Plug-in Development Environment packages. The basic HelloWorld program worked fine. However, the SWT version compilation failed with these errors:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems:

Display cannot be resolved to a type

Shell cannot be resolved to a type
```

Here's what I have done:

- Installed Eclipse 4.4.2 (Luna) using the software application in Fedora 21
- After realizing that it did not, in fact, come with JDT and PDE as was promised, I installed those packages from the Eclipse Luna Repository using the Eclipse help > install new software.
- Went to File > import > "Plug-in Development" > "Plug-ins and Fragments" and imported org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64 with the following specifications, per the tutorial's instructions

  - Import from: The active target platform
  - Plug-ins and Fragments to import: Select from all plug-ins and fragments found at specified location.
  - Import as: Projects with source folders
- Added org.eclipse.swt.gtk.linux.x86_64 to the buildpath of my project
- Right-clicked on the open class file and selected Source > "Organize imports"

When the project wouldn't compile, I followed the advice of [this post](http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/477829/) on the eclipse community forums, and installed all SWT packages from the luna repo with Eclipse's "install new software" function. I then deleted the project entirely, closed Eclipse, re-opened it, went to a different workspace and tried to do the entire tutorial over again to no avail.

I then tried to add these import statements to the top of the class file:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;
```

But Eclipse said that the package org.eclipse could not be resolved. However, the package was available to me in the package explorer, so I looked for the class files in the import statements. When I opened org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Display, it displayed this message at the top:

> There is no source file attached to the file Display.class

It seems like this is probably the source (no pun intended) of my problem. I didn't find anything helpful in further google searches. Any help getting this to compile and understanding why there are no source files attached to the class files is greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but imho you would be better off if you directly download the [Oomph installer](https://eclipse.org/downloads/index-developer.php) and use this one. Would save you lots of time.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post, but I just ran into this issue today and something I thought would be simple to fix took me hours.

This is the solution I used.

I'm on Windows 10, with the

> Eclipse J2EE 2019-09-17 R version

, but the RCP version worked as well.  I tried JAVA JDK 9, 10, 11, and finally

> JAVA JDK 1.8

and with this version of SWT:

> org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32x86_64

I got it to work.  I brought it in as project dependency only as I had tried adding the jar file as a variable and as an external jar, but nothing worked.

Below is a screenshot of it successfully running:

[image: Hello World SWT]

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue; then I changed Java Compliance level (in Preferences --> Java Compiler) to 1.8 in Preferences and it work.

Answer (score 0):

Try right-click -> quick fixes -> import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell to your directory